# Correct way to use CoreData Entity in this example

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a `CoreData`entity called "Person" with 3 attributes

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Person: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var image: NSData
@NSManaged var info: String

}
```

---

EDITED:
EXAMPLE: (I think my first "Table/chair" example caused more confusion then explanation.)

I have 7 `UIButton`s. When a `UIButto`n is tapped, My `TableView` is modally pushed and `TableView` `cell`s are populated with attribute values of all available `Person` via

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

I want to be able to double-tap a `cell`, which will close `TableView` and return to main`ViewController` the `Person` selected, and attach it to the `UIButton` that called the `TableView`. This `UIButton` will now display Selected`Person`'s image, name, and info (or have direct access to attribute values).

How should I go about making this possible?

Is there a `NSFetchRequest` Method that I could simply input something like...

```
NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person", attributeName: "name", String == "John Doe")
```

If so I could just pass the "name" value from `TableView` to Main`ViewController`, and store a `Person` reference in Main`ViewController` via something like this...

```
var PassedNameString = "John Doe"
var Person1: Person = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person", attributeName: "name", String == PassedNameString) as! Person
```

This way I'll have a reference to what `Person` entity is filling a "seat" and have direct access to it's info to read or edit.

---

My `CoreData` understanding is very low.

I've only learned how to create/store a file. I do not have a understanding of what is needed to recall a `CoreData` file and Edit if needed. I also don't know what kind of demand is put on the device when Fetching Vs holding a Reference to CoreData entry.

Comment: Store a reference. I assume this isn't your real situation - does a chair represent a view or a model object?

Comment: a chair is a slot, my MainViewController may need reference to a Maximum of 7 `Person` CoreData entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller have an array (or a dictionary if it suits you better) for the chairs. Each slot in the array represents a chair, and the index of the array links to the buttons you have (also should be in an array). The chair array holds instances of `Person` and is initially empty.

The table view controller should use a fetched results controller, with a batch size on the fetch. This is used to populate the table as usual. When a table row is selected the associated `Person` should be passed back and stored in the chair array.

Doing a second fetch is pointless and leads to name duplication issues.

Comment: Ok but I've been trying to "passed back and stored in the chair array" do I pass this `person` as a `person` or `NSManagedObject`. And every time I init a empty `var PersonPassed = NSManagedObject()` or `var PersonPassed = Person()` to fill upon selection and I get a "CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'MyProject.Person'". The Only other form of init I've used is when declaring locally `var NewPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject` when I save. What init to use?

Comment: I'm assuming that my init of an empty `var PersonSelected` and `var PersonPassed` has to somehow connect to the NSManagedObjectContext...Is this correct thinking? I have set up `var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate` and `var context: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()` in my TableViewController. How to tie this all together?

Comment: You pass the person that you get from the fetched results controller. Never create managed objects away from an entity and context. Only create new when you actually want something new in the data store - you don't. You don't want an empty person.

Comment: the `var NewPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject` is the code I use when adding to my CoreData.  I just want an empty reference I can then attach to Person... right now I'm working on populating a NSMutableArray with the Person: AnyObject selected from TableView...then in prepare for segue I plan to pass this AnyObject and insert into a NSMutableArray in MainViewController at Index corresponding to "seat". then when I need to access the info I'll call seat index and cast as Person.

Comment: would this be a correct method? if so how can I create my NSMutableArray in MainViewController to have 7 empty indexes, so that if I only know seat 4 I can insert Person at index3 and that index exists?

Comment: k, got the pass to happen, not sure if long-term efficient. I pull `AnyObject` from my `TableView` fetched results NSArray[indexPath.row] and place it in `var PassedPersonObject: NSObject()` and in TableView PrepareForSegue I insert this NSObject into MainViewControllers.PersonsArray (which equals [NSNull,NSNull,NSNull,NSNull,NSNull,NSNull,NSNull]) @ index according to chair.......So now my PersonsArray has the object at the correct index...Will I in the future be able to make changes to this object and make that save to this core data entry?

Comment: Fill the array with `NSNull` initially, not empty people, and check the class before use. You don't need the `NSObject()` - creating an unused empty object is a waste, just define the var. yes, you can change and save in future.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by I don't need NSObject()...If i try to define as `var PassedPersonObject: NSObject`...I get error on my ViewController class stating "Class 'ViewController' has no initializers.

Comment: As I understand swift that's creating a new `NSObject` instance that you don't need, you just want `var passedPersonObject` and the first letter should be lower case

Answer (score 0):

Think of CoreData as your database, that stores the data that is categorized by your model structures.

From your description, I would do a fetch request somewhere in your ViewController's loading sequence, say in ViewDidLoad, and store the results (Person objects) in an array of persons ... `var persons = [Person]()`. This can be a class variable. Then I would access the Person objects by calling array[index].

Let me know if this helps you with your thinking, or where you are confused.

```
var persons = [Person]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  ...do your fetch call...get back an array of objects as a result

  for person:Person in result {
    self.persons.append(person)
  }

  // now to access your Person objects anywhere in the class just call
  // self.persons[index] to get back an Person object 
}
```

Comment: issue could be that Users CoreData may contain 200+ Person but My ViewController for the most part only needs access to 7 (Max) 95% of the time, except when using tableView of all 200+ Person to make selection of our 7 needed. I edited my example to clarify my intent better.